# VBA Date Expression

Tags: c#, winforms, vba, report, reportviewer

Im trying to display the current weeks dates in a RDLC report. Im using this VBA expression in each Monday-Friday column headings -

```
="Wed " & Day(Parameters!weekStart.Value)-WeekDay(Parameters!weekStart.Value,FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 4
="Thu " & Day(Parameters!weekStart.Value)-WeekDay(Parameters!weekStart.Value,FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 5
="Fri " & Day(Parameters!weekStart.Value)-WeekDay(Parameters!weekStart.Value,FirstDayOfWeek.System) + 6
```

This works fine, until I get to a week where the onth changes mid-week, it continues counting. If the last day of the month in the selected week was a Tuesday 30th, it would carry on - Tues 31, Tues 32, Tues 33...

Any ideas how I can get this to display correctly?

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked this one out with the following VAB expression -

```
="Mon " & Day(DateValue(Parameters!weekStart.Value).AddDays(0))

="Tue " & Day(DateValue(Parameters!weekStart.Value).AddDays(1))

="Wed " & Day(DateValue(Parameters!weekStart.Value).AddDays(2))

="Thu " & Day(DateValue(Parameters!weekStart.Value).AddDays(3))

="Mon " & Day(DateValue(Parameters!weekStart.Value).AddDays(4))
```